# How to access a specific cell value of a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Can anyone help me how to access for example value of first cell in 4th column?

```
a b c d
1 2 3 5
g n m l
```

for example, how to access to value d from a data table structured and filled as above?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

If you need a weak reference to the cell value:

```
object field = d.Rows[0][3]
```

or

```
object field = d.Rows[0].ItemArray[3]
```

Should do it

If you need a strongly typed reference (string in your case) you can use the [DataRowExtensions.Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
string field = d.Rows[0].Field<string>(3);
```

(make sure System.Data is in listed in the namespaces in this case)

Indexes are 0 based so we first access the first row (0) and then the 4th column in this row (3)

Comment: @OP Just keep in mind that you'll often want to check first to ensure that there really are enough rows/columns when hard coding values like this.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13816531/638977
It suggestes `int number = dt.Rows[i].Field<int>(j);`

Answer (score 81):

```
string abc= dt.Rows[0]["column name"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also try (first cell in 4th column):

```
dt.Rows[0][3]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string value = row[3].ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. OP knows the position of the field and want to pull the value directly, not loop through each row to get to it, which is inefficient. Furthermore this will return the value of column 3 for each row, overwriting each time, and leaving OP with the value of `l`, rather than the value of `d`, the value they want.

Answer (score 7):

data d is in row 0 and column 3
for value d :

```
DataTable table;
String d = (String)table.Rows[0][3];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public V[] getV(DataTable dtCloned)
{

    V[] objV = new V[dtCloned.Rows.Count];
    MyClasses mc = new MyClasses();
    int i = 0;
    int intError = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtCloned.Rows)
    {
        try
        {
            V vs = new V();
            vs.R = int.Parse(mc.ReplaceChar(dr["r"].ToString()).Trim());
            vs.S = Int64.Parse(mc.ReplaceChar(dr["s"].ToString()).Trim());
            objV[i] = vs;
            i++;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //
            DataRow row = dtError.NewRow();
            row["r"] = dr["r"].ToString();
            row["s"] = dr["s"].ToString();
            dtError.Rows.Add(row);
            intError++;
        }
    }
    return vs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values in "SomeColumnName" are unique / distinct and that the value you are looking for in "NameOfColumnWhereIsTheValueYouLookingFor" is "Double".

```
double SomeDoubleValue = (double)SomeDataTable.Select("SomeColumnName = ValueWhichDetermineTheRowLocation").First()["NameOfColumnWhereIsTheValueYouLookingFor"]
```