# How to fill textbox with data from a DataTable

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I want to fill in the first column of data from a DataTable into a textbox.

What is the syntax to do that.

I have this so far, but get an error on the last line.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ChinatowndbConnString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM vwSchedule where scheduleid =" + scheduleid;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sd.Fill(dt);

    tbEvent.Text dt.Rows[0].Field<String>(0); // first field of first row, assuming that it's a string
```

Regards
Tea

Comment: So what's not working? If you replace `tbEvent.Text dt.Rows[0].Field<String>(0);` with `tbEvent.Text=dt.Rows[0].Field<String>(0);` it should work as expected (assuming that there are rows and that the first column's type is string).

Comment: could it be that coulmn 0 is not a string

Comment: My mistake, I forgot the = sign.

Comment: The exact line of error would have been pointed out by the compiler itself. A little introspection would have helped discover the obviously missing Equals sign.

Comment: @JKarthik: However, not worth a downvote since the question is clear. But it should be closed as _"too localized (unlikely to help any future visitors)"_.

Comment: The reason was "The question does not show any research effort". If every compiler error question is logged on StackOverflow, the site would indeed overflow :) Agree with your point too though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace

```
tbEvent.Text dt.Rows[0].Field<String>(0);
```

with

```
tbEvent.Text = dt.Rows[0].Field<String>(0);
```

it should work as expected (assuming that there are rows and that the first column's type is string).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an Equals in the last line syntax:

```
tbEvent.Text dt.Rows[0].Field<String>(0);
```

It should have been:

```
tbEvent.Text = dt.Rows[0].Field<String>(0);
```

Or

```
tblEvent.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0];
```

That should do it.

Reference: [Access cell value of datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022118/access-cell-value-of-datatable)