# Get Cell Value from a DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Here is a **DataTable dt**, which has lots of data.

I want to get the specific **Cell Value** from the DataTable, say **Cell[i,j]**. Where, 
i -> Rows and j -> Columns. I will iterate i,j's value with two `forloops`.

But I can't figure out how I can call a cell by its index.

Here's the code:

```
for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        var cell = dt.Rows[i][j];
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The `DataRow` has also an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z.aspx):

```
Object cellValue = dt.Rows[i][j];
```

But i would prefer the strongly typed [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) extension method which also supports [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int number = dt.Rows[i].Field<int>(j);
```

or even more readable and less error-prone with the name of the column:

```
double otherNumber = dt.Rows[i].Field<double>("DoubleColumn");
```

Comment: Primerily, My job is done. Thanks/ But all my columns are not string. some are double and int. how could i use Field<string> extension method?

Comment: @decoyer: That's a generic method, you can use it with any type. Edited my answer to demonstrate it with `int` and `double`.

Comment: Ok. Fine. But i am executing these codes in two loops(For). when j is changed, datatype may be changed. i am giving my code to make it better. I am editing my question.

Comment: @decoyer: In that case, stay with the simple indexer since you don't know what type it is.

Answer (score 14):

You probably need to reference it from the `Rows`rather than as a cell:

```
var cellValue = dt.Rows[i][j];
```

Answer (score 7):

You can iterate `DataTable` like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< dt.Rows.Count;i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <dt.Columns.Count ; j++)
        {
            object o = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j];
            //if you want to get the string
            //string s = o = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
        }
}
```

Depending on the type of the data in the `DataTable` cell, you can cast the object to whatever you want.

Answer (score 5):

To get cell column name as well as cell value :

```
List<JObject> dataList = new List<JObject>();

for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    JObject eachRowObj = new JObject();

    for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        string key = Convert.ToString(dataTable.Columns[j]);
        string value = Convert.ToString(dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[j]);

        eachRowObj.Add(key, value);

    }

    dataList.Add(eachRowObj);

}
```

Comment: there is an error ,dataList.Add(dataList);  should be dataList.Add(eachRowObj);

Answer (score 2):

You can call the indexer directly on the datatable variable as well:

```
var cellValue = dt[i].ColumnName
```

Answer (score -2):

If I have understood your question correctly you want to display one particular cell of your populated datatable? This what I used to display the given cell in my DataGrid.

```
var s  = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
txt_Country.Text = s.ToString();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: DataRow does not contain a definition for 'Cells'.