# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, textbox

I have to display values into text box while selecting drop down list. I have use data set to get values from db. The code is given below. Give me a proper solution. Thank you.

Code:

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        DataSet1TableAdapters.TextBoxTableTableAdapter tx;
        tx = new DataSet1TableAdapters.TextBoxTableTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = tx.GetstudData(int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
           {
           TextBox1.Text = (row["FirstName"]); // error shown here
           TextBox2.Text = (row["SecondName"]); // error shown here
           }
     }
```

The dt contains First Name and Last Name values. While selecting student ID the appropriate value shoud be shown in text box1 and textbox 2.

Sql query:

```
SELECT FirstName, SecondName FROM TextBoxTable WHERE (Id = @Id)
```

Source:

```
<div>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Data base:

[image]

Comment: What is the problem with setting of an appropriate [TextBox.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property from a [cell.value of the first row in datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816490/get-cell-value-from-a-datatable-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: if datatable has rows, then TextBox1.Text=dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"].

Comment: @pradeepvarma : If data table doesn't have rows, then what will be the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        DataSet1TableAdapters.TextBoxTableTableAdapter tx;
        tx = new DataSet1TableAdapters.TextBoxTableTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = tx.GetstudData(int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
           {
           TextBox1.Text = (row["FirstName"].ToString());
           TextBox2.Text = (row["SecondName"].ToString());
           }
     }
```

The names of the text boxes are different from the ones you have in the asp file. C# is a case sensitive language.

**EDIT:** You have to convert it. A simple .ToString() should do it. Try not to change the complete subject of the topic also. You should have open a new question...because this breaks all the correct answers.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to do :

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{

 TextBox1.Text = (row["FirstName"]);
 TextBox2.Text = (row["SecondName"]);
}
```

Comment: can you please apply the above solution in my code. I have pasted your solution in my code, but it is generating one error. That istext box 1 and 2 is not exist in the current context

Comment: Please try now with the above solution. I have updated the code .

Comment: Where you have updated the solution.! I couldn't find out? Please let me know.

Comment: i have changed the Textbox1 to TextBox1. Please copy the above code as is and paste in your solution. It should work !!!

Comment: Please mark this as answered and open another question for this . :)

Answer (score 1):

studentId is unique. DownDropList Contains Studentid. one student has one Name

```
if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue !="" && dt.Rows.Count()>0)
   {
       txtFirstname.Text= String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"]) ? "" : dt.Rows[0]["FirstName"];
     txtlastName.Text= String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dt.Rows[0]["LastName"]) ? "" : dt.Rows[0]["LastName"];      
}
 else
 {
   TextBox1.Text="";
  TextBox2.Text="";
 }
```