# How to get cell or row value from DataTable in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the **usert_id** value from datatable and assign it to session variable but I am not able to get the user_id in my code. How can I do this?

```
try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from students where user_name='" + loginname.Text + "' and user_password ='" + password.Text + "'", conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ShowMessage(dt.Row['.user_id.']); //<-- Problem happens here
                Session["user_id"] = "bar";
                Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Please enter valid Username and Password')</script>");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi do you get kind of error or something ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816490/get-cell-value-from-a-datatable-in-c-sharp

Comment: Should be using double quotes (") not an apostrophe (')

Comment: i think problem in ".user_id" to get the result , for more info you can follow this link .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774498/how-to-iterate-through-a-datatable
Hope it will help for you

Comment: data table is like a table . it contains datarows. if you select returns just one row , you shoul read the first datarow of DT then your selected field. just like jeremy answered

Answer (score 3):

.user_id. is not a Row index and I doubt it's the column name... you didn't surround it with dots did you? I think it should be using Row**s** not Row and double quotes:

```
ShowMessage(dt.Rows[0]["user_id"].ToString());
```