# Best way to find row data in DataTable using column numbers or column names?

Tags: c#, datatable

In extension to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816490/get-cell-value-from-a-datatable-in-c-sharp), while retrieving the cell value, are there any more advantages other than improving the readability by using the column names instead of column numbers?

```
for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        var cell = dt.Rows[i].Field<double>("DoubleColumn");
        //var cell = dt.Rows[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: I imagine another benefit would be that if you added a new column between two existing columns, you wouldn't have to update the index numbers for all subsequent columns.

Comment: that would be another advantage!!! can anyone tell me if there are any other....