# How can I take values from a table and put it in a for each

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I was creating a console application to check whether the users in a table are valid or not.
The idea is to take **each** user alias/email from a user table and put it in a for-each and compare it with the AD Account details and verify whether the user is active or not..
I have written the code to check in AD but I am not sure how can I take **each** values from a table and place it in a for-each

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: just added the code to check AD.. I have confused with the implementation

Comment: I'm sorry, I can see any change, did you know how to edit your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = yourTable;
string userName = string.empty;
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    userName = row["user_name"];
    //Perform the comparison here
}
```

> I wrote this code without IDE so there may be some syntax errors.
>   Let me know if it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This could help you out:

```
DataTable dt = GetTable();

for(int i = 0; i< dt.Rows.Count;i++)
    for (int j = 0; j <dt.Columns.Count ; j++)
    {
         object o = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j];
         //if you want to get the string
         //string s = o = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
    }
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816490/get-cell-value-from-a-datatable-in-c-sharp).

Another way around would be something like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{      
   var user = row["User"];
   // ["User"] is the name of the column. Change it to your column name.
}
```